# Empty space between .text and .fini data segments?

Tags: c, elf, objdump

I compiled a simple C program (`gcc -o file file.cpp`) and obtained the following output on running `objdump -h file`,

```
 12 .text         00000172  0000000000400400  0000000000400400  00000400  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
 13 .fini         00000009  0000000000400574  0000000000400574  00000574  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
```

I have a quick question here.

Why is there a gap of 2 bytes after the `.text` section? `0x400400 + 0x172 = 0x400572`, but the `.fini` section starts from `0x400574`? Has this got something to do with alignment?  I noticed similar gaps between some other sections as well.

Comment: Probably alignment. But why do you ask? Curiosity? Or is there another problem that lead to this question?

Comment: Trying to find out ways to identify the range of the `.text` segment in the virtual address space

Comment: probably you will find in your linker script something like this: `. = ALIGN(4);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last column of the output from `objdump -h file` is the alignment of the section. The alignment of `.fini` is `4` (`2**2` is 2 to the power of 2), which is why it starts at `0x400574` instead of `0x400572`.

When linking against glibc for x86-64, the alignment of `4` for the `.fini` section is specified in [`crti.o`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=sysdeps/x86_64/crti.S;hb=HEAD):

```
    .section .fini,"ax",@progbits
    .p2align 2
    .globl _fini
    .type _fini, @function
_fini:
```